# Problemas al cargar imágenes debido a los redireccionamientos en htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Me estoy encontrando con problemas para cargar algunas imágenes en función de la ruta donde me encuentre. Uso rutas absolutas, con lo que no entiendo que se enrede. El contenido del htaccess es este:

```
# Rewrite para admin.php
RewriteRule ^Panel-Control/ admin.php [L]

# Rewrite para nuevo_articulo.php
RewriteRule ^Editar-Articulo/([0-9]+)/ nuevo_articulo.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Nuevo-Articulo/ nuevo_articulo.php [L]
RewriteRule ^Editar-Categoria/([0-9]+)/ nueva_categoria.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Crear-Categoria/ nueva_categoria.php [L]

# Rewrite para articulo.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-].+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-].+)/ articulo.php?id=$2&categoria=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-].+)/ articulo.php?categoria=$1 [L]
```

Y me da problemas por ejemplo al cargar una imagen con esta ruta: `http://localhost/carpeta_origen/imagenes/nombre_imagen.jpg` en `http://localhost/carpeta_origen/ruta/`, sin embargo si accedo a un nivel más no tengo ningún problema, por ejemplo `http://localhost/carpeta_origen/ruta/23/ruta/`

Creía que se estaba pudiendo interferir con alguna línea de código, y por ello he elegido hacer pruebas e introducir las imágenes dentro de 2 carpetas, de tal forma que la ruta me quedase:
`http://localhost/carpeta_origen/imagenes/carpeta_1/carpeta_2/nombre_imagen.jpg`

Pero no me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en estas 2 reglas:

```python
# Rewrite para articulo.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-].+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-].+)/ articulo.php?id=$2&categoria=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-].+)/ articulo.php?categoria=$1 [L]
```

Fijate que `.+` coincide con cualquier cantidad de caracteres. Por ejemplo, la segunda regla coincide con cualquier URL que empiece por un alfanumérico o `-` y tenga una `/` en algún lugar!!!

Hay 2 cosas a corregir:

- El punto va dentro de la clase de caracteres para que no signifique *cualquier caracter*: `[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]`
- Hay que usar `$` para que coincida con la posición final, exigiendo que coincida con la URL completa, y no sólo con el inicio.

Pero además, si todas las reglas de tus "secciones" reescriben a `algun_nombre.php`, eso haría que también coincida con tu última regla, que tiene sólo la categoría. Fijate como siguen el mismo patrón:
`/articulo_articulo.php`
`/alguna-categoria`

Podríamos verificar las que no estén terminadas con `.php`, con algo como:

```python
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+)/?$ articulo.php?categoria=$1 [L]
```

Pero creo que en este caso, te conviene configurar que todas las reescrituras sean finales, cambiando [`[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) por [`[END]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end).

Y haciendo que vaya a `articulo.php` únicamente si no encontró un archivo o un directorio con ese nombre:

---

**Código:**

```python
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite para admin.php
RewriteRule ^Panel-Control admin.php [END]

# Rewrite para nuevo_articulo.php
RewriteRule ^Editar-Articulo/(\d+)(?:/|$) nuevo_articulo.php?id=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^Nuevo-Articulo(?:/|$) nuevo_articulo.php [END]
RewriteRule ^Editar-Categoria/(\d+)(?:/|$) nueva_categoria.php?id=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^Crear-Categoria(?:/|$) nueva_categoria.php [END]

# Rewrite para articulo.php
RewriteRule ^([-\w.]+)/(\d+)/[-\w.]+/?$ articulo.php?id=$2&categoria=$1 [END,QSA]
# Rewrite para articulo.php (sólo categoría, y sólo si no es un archivo/dir existente)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-\w.]+)/?$ articulo.php?categoria=$1 [END,QSA]
```

<sup>- También modifiqué algunos detalles que no eran necesarios, pero que me gustaban más así.</sup>

Subí una demo a un hosting gratuito si querés probarlo:

1. http://mariano.uphero.com/132991/carpeta_origen/imagenes/nombre_imagen.jpg
2. http://mariano.uphero.com/132991/Panel-Control/
3. http://mariano.uphero.com/132991/Panel-Control/bla-bla-bla
4. http://mariano.uphero.com/132991/Editar-Articulo/123
5. http://mariano.uphero.com/132991/categoria/654/nombre-articulo

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! La parte que me fallaba me funciona, pero ahora no me funciona el resto, si entro en cualquier otra sección me carga la página accediendo a `articulo.php`. Si voy por ejemplo al panel de control ahora, me sigue redirigiendo a `articulo.php` que evidentemente no me carga nada porque no tiene los parámetros en la URL para cargar la información. Y esa regla antes me funcionaba y está antes de la regla que hemos comentado. No entiendo porqué ahora se la pasa de largo.

Comment: Sí así es, de ahí que no entienda que se salte la regla del panel de control por ejemplo.

Comment: @JetLagFox perdón, me pasé por alto que iba a coincidir al buscar la reescritura. Modifiqué la respuesta, y esta vez lo probé antes de responder. Ahora funciona :-)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Funciona para todo menos para la página principal. Estoy probando con `RewriteRule ^/ index.php [END]`, pero no me funciona. El resto sí. Valido la respuesta por supuesto, a ver si consigo encontrar la forma para que no me de problemas con la página principal.

Comment: @JetLagFox agregué la condición de que no reescriba si existe el directorio, con eso te permite ir a `/carpeta_origen/` sin reescribir

Comment: @JetLagFox Para referencia a futuro, siempre intenta usar `$` en todas las expresiones regulares. Por ejemplo `^\w+` coincide con `pagina`, pero también con `pagina%()/algo-mas---.php/bla`. En cambio `^\w+$` sólo con `pagina`.

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo. Ya me funciona todo con tu solución. Le echaré un vistazo cuando tengas más tiempo porque pensaba que controlaba lo suficiente como para tener los problemas con los que me he encontrado.